# How to nonce verify WP_List_Table

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a custom plugin by the custom table. I want to display the data in the WP_List_Table. that is working perfectly. Various way I tried to verify nonce but that is not working perfectly. I am submitting the following script. check the script. Specially process_bulk_action() and column_cb($item).Can any one give me the suggestion how to do verify nonce.

```
class EmaillogList extends \WP_List_Table
{
    function __construct()
    {
        global $status, $page;

        parent::__construct(array(
            'singular' => 'person',
            'plural' => 'persons',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * [REQUIRED] this is a default column renderer
     *
     * @param $item - row (key, value array)
     * @param $column_name - string (key)
     * @return HTML
     */
    function column_default($item, $column_name)
    {   
        return $item[$column_name];
    }

    /**
     * [OPTIONAL] this is example, how to render specific column
     *
     * method name must be like this: "column_[column_name]"
     *
     * @param $item - row (key, value array)
     * @return HTML
     */
    /*function column_age($item)
    {
        return '<em>' . $item['age'] . '</em>';
    }*/

    /**
     * [OPTIONAL] this is example, how to render column with actions,
     * when you hover row "Edit | Delete" links showed
     *
     * @param $item - row (key, value array)
     * @return HTML
     */
    function column_name($item)
    {
        // links going to /admin.php?page=[your_plugin_page][&other_params]
        // notice how we used $_REQUEST['page'], so action will be done on curren page
        // also notice how we use $this->_args['singular'] so in this example it will
        // be something like &person=2
        $actions = array(
            'delete' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=delete&id=%s">%s</a>', $_REQUEST['page'], $item['id'], __('Delete', 'cltd_example')),
        );

        return sprintf('%s %s',
            $item['name'],
            $this->row_actions($actions)
        );
    }

    /**
     * [REQUIRED] this is how checkbox column renders
     *
     * @param $item - row (key, value array)
     * @return HTML
     */
    function column_cb($item)
    {
        return sprintf(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="%s" />',
            $item['id']
        );
    }

    /**
     * [REQUIRED] This method return columns to display in table
     * you can skip columns that you do not want to show
     * like content, or description
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function get_columns()
    {
        $columns = array(
            'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />', //Render a checkbox instead of text
            'estatus' => __('Status', 'orange-wp-smtp'),
            'recipient_email' => __('To', 'orange-wp-smtp'),
            'esubject' => __('Subject', 'orange-wp-smtp'),
            'sender_name' => __('Sender Name', 'orange-wp-smtp'),      
        );
        return $columns;
    }

    /**
     * [OPTIONAL] This method return columns that may be used to sort table
     * all strings in array - is column names
     * notice that true on name column means that its default sort
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function get_sortable_columns()
    {
        $sortable_columns = array(
            'estatus'   => array('estatus', true),
        );
        return $sortable_columns;
    }

    /**
     * [OPTIONAL] Return array of bult actions if has any
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function get_bulk_actions()
    {
        $actions = array(
            'delete' => 'Delete'
        );
        return $actions;
    }

    /**
     * [OPTIONAL] This method processes bulk actions
     * it can be outside of class
     * it can not use wp_redirect coz there is output already
     * in this example we are processing delete action
     * message about successful deletion will be shown on page in next part
     */
    function process_bulk_action()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'orgsmtp_logs'; // do not forget about tables prefix

        if ('delete' === $this->current_action()) {
            $ids = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : array();
            if (is_array($ids)) $ids = implode(',', $ids);

            if (!empty($ids)) {
                $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id IN($ids)");
            }
        }
    }



    /**
     *
     * It will get rows from database and prepare them to be showed in table
     */
    function prepare_items()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'orgsmtp_logs'; // do not forget about tables prefix

        $per_page = 20; // constant, how much records will be shown per page

        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = array();
        $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();

        // here we configure table headers, defined in our methods
        $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);

        // [OPTIONAL] process bulk action if any
        $this->process_bulk_action();

        // will be used in pagination settings
        $total_items = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM $table_name");

        // prepare query params, as usual current page, order by and order direction
        $paged = isset($_REQUEST['paged']) ? max(0, intval($_REQUEST['paged'] - 1) * $per_page) : 0;
        $orderby = (isset($_REQUEST['orderby']) && in_array($_REQUEST['orderby'], array_keys($this->get_sortable_columns()))) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'id';
        $order = (isset($_REQUEST['order']) && in_array($_REQUEST['order'], array('asc', 'desc'))) ? $_REQUEST['order'] : 'asc';
        
        // notice that last argument is ARRAY_A, so we will retrieve array
        $this->items = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY $orderby $order LIMIT %d OFFSET %d", $per_page, $paged), ARRAY_A);

        //configure pagination
        $this->set_pagination_args(array(
            'total_items' => $total_items, // total items defined above
            'per_page' => $per_page, // per page constant defined at top of method
            'total_pages' => ceil($total_items / $per_page) // calculate pages count
        ));
    }
    
}
```